# Is there a way to make "pynput" clicks on "next" or "cancel" buttons in exe installer?

Tags: pynput

I made a python script to automate sum apps on windows, and its working very fine.
I am using pynput to click on elements (by giving the coordinates)and to insert a text to fields.
Like i said every thing is working very fine, the problem is when i am trying to click on a button (next, cancel...) on an exe installer, the mouse do not move and do not click on the given coordinates when the installer window is in focus.
when putting the installer window out of focus, the mouse starts moving and clicking.
Help please !!!

Thanks a lot

Comment: You need to show us the code otherwise we do not know where the problem is.

Comment: def click_button(dict, button):
 mouse.position = (dict[button][0], dict[button][1])
 time.sleep(0.5)
 mouse.click(Button.left, 1)
 write_to_log("Clicked on %s" %button)
 print "Clicked on %s" %button

Comment: Iv'e resolved the problem :) it was an "admin privileges" .